# Selecting specific text part of html text code

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Please, how can I get text "There is no event, try later." from this html?

```
...</option></select><!-- --></div><div class="media_container__no-match-tracker"><div><div><div class="icon icon--football icon--size_auto"></div><div class="icon icon--volleyball icon--size_auto"></div><div class="icon icon--handball icon--size_auto"></div><div class="icon icon--hockey icon--size_auto"></div><div class="icon icon--basketball icon--size_auto"></div><div class="icon icon--tennis icon--size_auto"></div></div> There is no event, try later. </div></div></div></div></div><div class="app_column__bottom_row" data-v-eb1959b8=""><div class="app_column__bottom_row_wrapper" data-v-eb1959b8=""><div class="app_column__bottom_row_content" data-v-eb1959b8=""><div class="tab_menu chatMenu" data-v-4d018892="" data-v-eb1959b8=""><div ...
```

I try:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div')
```

but return only:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d79e3bdd44586c81ae5922410f0c20dd", element="405526fe-7e1a-4552-af5a-70cfb341e129")>
```

I use python3, selenium, bs4, headless chrome. Thank you.

Comment: Please share the full code you tried / link to the website

Comment: @MendelG link: https://live.ifortuna.sk/zapas/LSK1657222   I need find text: "Tento zápas nemá tracker, vyberte si iný."

Comment: You need to .text after you find the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit hard to read your code and html but try this xpath locator:

```
//div[@class='media_container__no-match-tracker']
```

And to return the text of the element:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="media_container__no-match-tracker"]').text
```

Answer (score 0):

@DMart

Thank you, this is what I need. Can I one more question? Site is dynamical, so this element is not in code everityme I scrape it. When it doesnt, thist driver.find... return:

```
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="media_container__no-match-tracker"]').text
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):



  File "<ipython-input-95-8dcfa123bd2a>", line 1, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="media_container__no-match-tracker"]').text

  File "C:\Users\Miro\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)

  File "C:\Users\Miro\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']

  File "C:\Users\Miro\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

  File "C:\Users\Miro\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class="media_container__no-match-tracker"]"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=86.0.4240.193)
```

How I can use this as condition? If element is on the site print it, if not print("element isnt on this url").

Comment: use a wait: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/1387701

Comment: @DMart Thank you